# TypeError: Improper input parameters were entered

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, scipy-optimize

I trying to use the fsolve function from scipy.optimize library to solve a non-linear equation changing the parameteres of the equation, but when I run the code, I receive the following error message:

TypeError: Improper input parameters were entered.

I reviewed the program multiple times and I still can't find the problem. I've searched through the internet and I didn't find any documentation or people with the same problem. 
I wrote this code for the function:

```
def Rolling(h,ho,b,mi,R,sig,load):
  Dh  = ho - h
  hm  = (h+ho)*0.5
  Lp  = (R*Dh)**0.5
  Q   = mi*Lp/hm
  P   = sig*(b/Q*(exp(Q)-1)*Lp)

  return P-load
```

I wrote a loop where the values of the equation changes, but I always what to find the value of 'h' for every situation, so I use fsolve:

```
h = fsolve(lambda H: Rolling(H,ho,b,mi,R,sig,load),hi)
```

The problem occurs in this line.

P.S.: I already tried using args=(), but returns the same message.

Comment: Can you add a full code example?  At the moment, it isn't clear what the type/values of the variables you're passing into `fsolve` are.

Comment: I already solved the problem, the problem is was that R was a empty list in the first loop. Thank you for the advise.